# Bandwitdh limits by IP

Tags: linux, networking

It's impossible for me to connect to the internet network with a speed higher than 10Mbps because we're limited to it from the router (which is unaccessible for us) in the place where I live.

I have already set different IP alias on an interface but it doesn't increase the speed. Can I configure them running Linux or MacOS in order to bypass this speed limitation?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You've not told us enough about the device that is restricting the bandwidth for anyone to identify an adequate answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

No. Bits are bits are bits. Whether the client machine that sends or receives the packets runs Windows, MacOS, Linux. or [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M), it's irrelevant to routers who choke your bandwidth. All the router cares about is the IP address.

Now you could use several machines, virtual or real, each using a different IP address, to get more bandwidth, if their traffic is not otherwise discernible as from the same source.

Comment: Not entirely true. For example, a router that limits bandwidth by IP addresses would be unable to prevent a device using several IPs from aggregating the combined bandwidth.

Comment: While well intentioned, this question is too broad, and honestly this answer can be posted as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

### No

The throttling of your connection does not happen at your computer (whatever OS it's running), it happens at the router. The protocol used by the ISPs to communicate with their routers is [DOCSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS). Bypassing it is not impossible but definitely out of range for most people.

There are some who have done it in the past:

- [Blake Self & bitemytaco - Hacking DOCSIS For Fun and Profit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaaJ86K-ovE)
- [Hacking DOCSIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFnfYElMGe0) (German)

Comment: Is DOCSIS used in DSL routers?

Comment: @K7AAY [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS#Equipment)